# simple program using too much cpu

Tags: c, ubuntu, load, cpu

Edit : Why is this question getting downvoted?

I am wondering why the following code uses very much CPU. I can not see anything, which could cause this issue.
It is the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>


void main(){

    clock_t begin;
    double time_spent;
    int i = 0;


    while(1){

        begin = clock();
        time_spent = 0;
        while(time_spent < 60) {
                time_spent = (double)(clock() - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        }
        i++;
        printf("Eine Minute vergangen           %i\n", i);
    }
}
```

This program basically checks when one minute has elapsed, counts how many minutes are done yet and prints it out.

I am running this on ubuntu terminal and it sucks my CPU. Can someone help me figuring this out?

Comment: You have an essentially empty loop running for a minute, of course this will eat your cpu.

Comment: What do you mean by *"it sucks my CPU"*? It's an endless loop, running continuously.

Comment: But why is this an "of course" thing? Can you explain why it is so?

Comment: What would you expect the computer to do? Should the CPU think _'oh nothings going to change for the next 60 seconds, so I'll just take a nap and come back later'_?

Comment: I expected that the computer somehow sees that this is not some heavy processing and therefore knows how much power it has to deliver.
Can you tell me how I can tell this to the computer?

Comment: By googling what has been discussed below.

Comment: Oh Thank you Weather I did not see this! :)

Comment: I just looked sleep() up and do not think this can solve my problem anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitting at the bus station, waiting for the bus to arrive in an hour or so, you do not look at your watch every second, milli second, ..., don't you? But that's exactly what you told the CPU to do, even worth you told it to "look up the time" as often as possible, as fast as it can.

So depending on the accuracy necessary tell the CPU to take a longer or shorter break between checking the time.

If an accuracy of 1s would be enough, then wait 1s between testing the time by adding

```
      sleep(1);
```

into the inner `while`-loop.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very nice explanation.
Schönen Abend.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to slow down the second while loop (like a sleep or IO operation) so it runs as fast as the OS and processor will execute it.

Comment: And that is the reason why the whole CPU is concentrating in executing this program, even it is a very trivial one?

Comment: @OcK Yes. The CPU is just executing instructions in your program. It doesn't know or care that your program is trivial.

Comment: The only way you can stop the processor executing your code is to surrender the rest of its time slice when its condition is not met, and `sleep()` does that, AFAIK.

Comment: @WeatherVane POSIX defines `sched_yield` which will also instruct the OS that the program is relinquishing the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

By putting `while(1)`, you are saying 'run the loop for infinity'. This means your loop will carry on executing the same process over and over again forever. There is no other conditional statement to tell it when to stop, so at compile time, it will recognise this and when you run it, the computer will run the program as fast as possible forever. Overtime, this will use a lot of CPU resources, which is what you have noticed as sucking up the CPU.